# XLL and EXCEL : Drag or Load

Tags: c++, export-to-excel, xll, xlw

I have a problem loading my XLL into Excel. I use XLW to generate my XLL , and I use Excel 2007. When I drag the file on my spreadsheet, I can use all my Xll functions, and it works well. 
However when I load it using Excel-Add in , the file is loaded but none of my functions are there.

I tried the same thing with Excel 2010, and it is worse. When I drag the XLL file into my spreadsheet, the XLL is opened as it was a text file, and I cant make it work like I did in Excel 2007,
I can load it using Excel-Addin , but I cant get any of my XLL functions.

Do you know what is the problem ?

EDIT : I followed the steps in the following video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mpw5_JW7T4

EDIT 2 : In Excel 2007, when I drag the xll to the spreadsheet, it works but the dll is missing in the Add-Ins section.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: In which way is this related to [tag:c++]? If you have some c++ code example to show, please edit your question to do so.

Comment: the XLL was produce by XLW c++. Even the defaut example from XLW is not working , unless I drag it to the spreadsheet.

Comment: this example : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mpw5_JW7T4

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Comment: I stopped using xll and Xlw, but decided to use a dll